# How to return current incremented value in table via STORED PROCEDURE after INSERT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To get currently incremented value in table after insert command

After googling I have found one function as `INDENT_INCR('<table_name>')`, therefore I have tried this function.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[usp_Insert]
 @flag char(3)=null,
 @udise varchar(11)=null,
 @mgmt_certificate image=null
as
BEGIN
     declare @sm_incremented_id int=null
     if(@flag='IIA') --Insert new UDISE into all tables
       begin
            insert into school_master(udise_no) values(@udise) /* SCHOOL MASTER */

            set @sm_incremented_id=IDENT_INCR('school_master')


            insert into documents_attached(schoolid,udise_no,Order_Copy_Fresh_Mgmt) values(@sm_incremented_id,@udise,@mgmt_certificate) /* DOCUMENTS */

       end
END
```

In table there are 4 records with id's 1,2,3,4. I have deleted 2,3,4. Then inserted new record and id is 5. But this function returning me 1 always. Why?

Comment: `INDENT_INCR` returns the incremental value of the `IDENTITY` column, not the value that was inserted. So for a column defined as an `IDENTITY(1,1)` it would be `1`, and for an `IDENTITY(1,10)` it would be `10`. You probably want `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: Ya actually In my table I have already set ID column to `IDENTITY(1,1)` previously. Therefore I am using `INDENT_INCR` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for what would the next value be then you can use **[`IDENT_CURRENT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** and **[`IDENT_INCR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-incr-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** functions as

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('SchemaName.TableName') + IDENT_INCR('SchemaName.TableName')
```

If you are looking for the last identity value inserted into an identity column, you can use the **[`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** as

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Note that `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in *the same scope*.